# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Command Prompt?

Tags: java

I have a problem with running my code in cmd.
So I export my project from eclipse oxygen,
in command prompt I do

```
javac SolverCode.java
```

That Was all right.

Then I do:

```
java SolverCode
```

And that is where I got my error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SolverCode
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mazeSolver/SolverCode (wrong name: SolverCode)
```

I have jre and jdk installed I have set the Path to my deafult jdk and everything.
My Path is set to:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\CommonFiles\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin
```

It just wont work in cmd (in Eclipse it works).
Do you have any Idea why is that happening?

Comment: What is the package of `SoverCode` class? Is the fully qualified class name `mazeSolver.SolverClass`?

Comment: Package name is mazeSolver

Comment: Class name is SolverCode

Comment: I do not have any duplicates of this class, package or project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your package folder into your classpath. So if you are in your root source folder, then you run following command.
`java -cp . mazesolver.SolverCode`

[image]

Comment: Amith Kurmar Thank you! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the class is in `mazeSolver` package you need to specify the fully qualified name as:

```
java mazeSolver.SolverCode
```

Comment: Now I get this :                                                                                                   
Error: Could not find or load main class mazeSolver.SolverCode
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mazeSolver.SolverCode